# Fabric.Path Object's object.path does not give updated path when scaled or changed position in Fabric js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabric js for my project.

I have a use case where I want an object to animate along the boundary of other fabric object. Similar to motion paths in power point. To implement this, I am creating a fabric.Path object and using this path, I am getting all the boundary points of the object and animating the object along these points. The code is as shown below.

```
<script src="./js/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas
  id="c"
  width="500"
  height="500"
  style="border: 1px solid #ccc"
></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="main">
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
  var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 30,
    fill: "#f55"
  });

  canvas.add(circle);

  var line = new fabric.Path(
    "M 0 0 L 200 100 L 170 200 z",
    {
      fill: "",
      stroke: "black",
      objectCaching : true
    }
  );
  line.set({ name: "dummy" });
  canvas.add(line);

  var points = getPathValues("M 0 0 L 200 100 L 170 200 z", 1000);
   function getPathValues(path_val, samples) {
    var path = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "path"
    );
    path.setAttribute("d", path_val);
    var points = [];
    var len = path.getTotalLength();
    var step = (step = len / samples);
    for (var i = 0; i <= len; i += step) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(i);
      points.push(p.x);
      points.push(p.y);
    }
    return points;
  }

  var i = 0;

  var interval = setInterval(function animate() {
      i = i + 2;
      if (i > points.length) {
        // clearInterval(interval);
        i = 0;
      }

      circle.left = line.left + points[i] - circle.radius;
      circle.top = line.top + points[i + 1] - circle.radius;
      canvas.renderAll();
    }, 10);
```

With all this working well, Now when I scale or change position of the path object, I want to take the changed path, get the updated points and animate the object along those points. Now the problem is that when scale or change the position if the path object, The object.path for it is not getting updated automatically. I am not able to get the change path values which is needed for me to generate boundary points.

1. Is there any way to get the update path of the Fabric.Path object?
2. Is there any way to get the path of a normal fabric object?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the path data is transformed such that it becomes relative to the object's plane.

You should familiarize with relative planes and basics of matrix multiplication, at least the concepts.

This is why scale etc. don't affect it.

You need to apply the object's transformation matrix (via preTransform) to the points.

I can imagine this is too much.

That is why I have exposed `fabric.util.sendPointToPlane`. Check that out and it will save you a lot of headache.

`fabric.util.sendPointToPlane(point, from, to)`, in your case `fabric.util.sendPointToPlane(point, object.calcTransformMatrix(), null)` will send the point to the canvas plane.

I wrote a post regarding relative planes but I can't find it, somewhere in fabric discussions

Comment: I am unable to find anything regarding fabric.util.sendPointToPlane() in the fabric documentation or the web. Can you provide any jsfiddle of the link to your post regarding the same

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else encounters this problem: after changing path do this:

```
this.object.path = /* New path */
this.object.dirty = true
```

Its solve for me